# Rspec instance variables and controller testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing a bowling score calculator, and I'm trying to set up RSpec tests, but for some reason I can't get my tests to work correctly.

players_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PlayersController do
  let(:player_names) { ["player1",
                        "player2",
                        "player3",
                    "player4"] }

  describe "POST bowl" do
    before(:each) do
      @game = Game.create!
      player_names.each do |name|
        Player.create!(:name => name)
      end
      @game.players = Player.all
      Player.all.each do |player|
        (0..9).each do |number|
          player.frames << Frame.create(:number => number)
        end
      end
    end
    describe "for the player's third bowl" do
      before(:each) do
        @game.players[@game.current_player].frames[9].update_attributes({:number => 9, :first_bowl => "X", :second_bowl => "X", :score => 20})
        @game.update_attributes({:current_player => 0, :current_frame => 9})
      end

      describe "if the bowl is a number score" do
        before(:each) do
          post :bowl, {:score => "5", :id => @game.id}
        end

        it "should update the player's score" do
          @game.players[@game.current_player].frames[@game.current_frame].score.should == 25
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

players_controller.rb

```
def bowl
    @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    @score = params[:score]

    @current_player = @game.current_player
    @current_frame = @game.current_frame
    @player = @game.players[@current_player]

    @frame = @player.frames[@current_frame]

    if @frame.first_bowl.nil?
      @frame.first_bowl = @score
      if @score == "/"
        raise "Error"
      end
      if @score == "X" && @frame.number == 9
        @frame.bonus = 2
      end
      @frame.score = (/\A[0-9]\z/ === @score ? @score.to_i : 10)
    elsif @frame.second_bowl.nil?
      @frame.second_bowl = @score
      if @frame.score + @score.to_i > 10
        raise "Error"
      end
      if @score == "X"
        if @frame.number != 9 || (@frame.number == 9 && @frame.first_bowl != "X") # can't be a spare has to be number or strike
          raise "Error"
        end
      end
      if @score == "/" && @frame.number == 9
        @frame.bonus = 1
      end
      if /\A[0-9]\z/ === @score
        @frame.score += @score.to_i
      elsif @score == "/"
        @frame.score = 10
      elsif @score == "X"
        @frame.score = 20
      end
    elsif @frame.third_bowl.nil?
      @frame.third_bowl = @score
      if @frame.number != 9
        raise "Error"
      end
      @frame.bonus = nil
      @frame.update_attributes({:score => (/\A[0-9]\z/ === @score ? @frame.score + @score.to_i : @frame.score + 10)})
    else
      raise "Error"
    end
    @frame.save

    if @game.current_frame > 0
      @prev_frame = @player.frames[@frame.number-1]

      if @prev_frame.nil?
        @prev_frame = Frame.create(:number => @game.current_frame-1)
        @player.frames << @prev_frame
        @player.frames = @player.frames.sort_by { |f| f.number }
      end

      update_scores
    end
```

The spec in question is players_controller_spec.rb and at the start of the tests I'm creating a new game with 4 players and each player with 10 frames. Before each test, I'm setting a certain frame's values to be fit what I'm trying to test. The test above is an example where I want to make sure that bowling a score of 5 on the third bowl on the last frame correctly updates the score. But, even though in the debugger I see that the score is updated in the frame (when I debug in the controller method), once I return to the Rspec test, it doesn't work. It expects 25 but gets nil. Is there something I'm missing about how instance variables are transferred between specs and controllers?

Comment: You're much more likely to get a good answer if you focus on one case and post code specifically for that test, that way we have something to focus on. Posting the link to your code base is way too open-ended: post the code for the specific case you are asking about (i.e. from line 393) so we don't have to go hunt it down.

Comment: Got it - I added a specific snippet of the spec code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first off there is no 'transferring'. The controller and the example are 2 completely independent objects, each with their own instance variables (You can use the `assigns` spec helper to retrieve the value of a controller instance variable though).

That's not the root cause of your issue. You do, even before the controller executes, have an `@game` instance variable that is the game you are interested in. However with activerecord, every time you do `Game.find` you'll receive separate ruby objects (corresponding to the same database row). Once the row has been loaded from the database it doesn't notice changes made to the database behind its back.

You can reload the object with `@game.reload`

As a side note this sort of stuff is easier to work with if most of that logic was pushed down into one of your models rather than sitting in the controller.